# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement backports.tempfile (from z3c.RML)

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, reportlab, rml

I have got an Debian machine with the folowing packages installed:
python3, python-virtualenv, python3-virtualenv, python3-reportlab

I created an virtual environment with:

```
virtualenv --system-site-packages -p python3 venv
source venv/bin/activate
```

After this i tryed to install the z3c.RML package with pip:

```
pip install z3c.RML
```

This is the output i get:

```
Downloading/unpacking z3c.RML
  Downloading z3c.rml-3.2.0.tar.gz (1.7MB): 1.7MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-zuhtd3uu/z3c.RML/setup.py) egg_info for package z3c.RML

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.png' found under directory 'src/z3c/rml/tests/output'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pdf' found under directory 'src/z3c/rml/tests/output'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.png' found under directory 'src/z3c/rml/tests/expected'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
Downloading/unpacking PyPDF2>=1.25.1 (from z3c.RML)
  Downloading PyPDF2-1.26.0.tar.gz (77kB): 77kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-zuhtd3uu/PyPDF2/setup.py) egg_info for package PyPDF2

Downloading/unpacking Pygments (from z3c.RML)
  Downloading Pygments-2.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (841kB): 841kB downloaded
Downloading/unpacking backports.tempfile (from z3c.RML)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement backports.tempfile (from z3c.RML) (from versions: 1.0rc1, 1.0rc1)
Cleaning up...
No distributions matching the version for backports.tempfile (from z3c.RML)
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Someone knows what i did wrong? - thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the owner of backports.tempfile never released a final version of the package. You need to pass the `--pre` option to `pip`. If you do not want all your packages to be installed with pre-release versions, do:

```
pip install --pre backports.tempfile

pip install z3c.rml
```